# using IPC between a windows service and win32 application C++

Tags: c++, windows

I have written a windows service and I want to communicate(IPC) it with a win32 application(Desktop), can anyone tell me what should I exactly do for making this communication. In my case my Service is server and other process is client. Process should establish connection with the service whenever a user launches it on his machine.

Comment: Could you be a little clearer about the communication mechanism and sequence? In other words, does the app initiate communication with the service when the app starts, or the other way around?

Comment: yup, app initiates communication with the windows service when it starts. I simply want to open a named pipe between app and service.How can I do that. In other words how do I grant permissions to app to access Service through service control manager.

Comment: A simple way is to create a COM server, which exports several objects.

Answer (score 3):

I have written services which support named pipes like you describe.  I do not have to do anything special to set permissions for the client to open & read/write the named pipe.  I found the following Microsoft articles useful when developing my code:

"The Complete Service Sample": 
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540476(VS.85).aspx
"Named Pipe Server Using Completion Routines" : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365601(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Following is a list of options for inter-process communication on Windows:
1. Component Object Model (COM)
2. Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
3. Windows Sockets

You can set service type as Automatic, mean it will start once the machine up& running
Please refer.
https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/sharedmemory/article.php/c2879/Shared-Memory-Inter-Process-Communication-IPC.htm